# Automatically switching output audio device on 14.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack, external-soundcard

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I recently bought a [Schiit Fulla USB DAC/Amp](http://schiit.com/products/fulla). I want Ubuntu to automatically switch audio output to this device when I plug it in as opposed to me having to manually set it every time. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a better solution exists but a udev rule may be what you are looking for.

Open the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules` search for `LABEL="pulseaudio_check_usb"` and add your custom rule to the end of this block.

- Have a look at this: [How to change pulseaudio sink with  "pacmd set-default-sink" during playback?](https://askubuntu.com/q/71863/40581)
- Use `lsusb` to get your USB vendor and product ID (Example: vendor `0d8c` product `0102` in `Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0d8c:0102 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM106 Like Sound Device`)
- The rule probably looks like below, but I haven't tested it and I wouldn't want it in my audio setup.

  ```
  # My custom rule to switch to Schiit Fulla everytime it gets connected
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1234", RUN+="pacmd set-default-sink …"
  ```
- To let the changes in the rule take effect you need to restart udev: [What is the correct way to restart udev?](https://askubuntu.com/q/82470/40581)
- I'm not sure if `90-pulseaudio.rules` is the right place for such a rule, I just know that I had to configure another device and use `ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}` in conjunction with a custom conf file instead of the `RUN` parameter. The disadvantage of modifying this configuration file is that it will be replaced when the corresponding package gets updated.